# Resize a bitmap in CS50 of Harvard's Set 4

Tags: bitmap

I find that a bitmap provided with followed properties.

```
{biSize = 40, biWidth = 3, biHeight = -3, biPlanes = 1, biBitCount = 24, biCompression = 0, biSizeImage = 36, biXPelsPerMeter = 2834,   biYPelsPerMeter = 2834, biClrUsed = 0, biClrImportant = 0}
```

My question is that why its biSizeImage is't 3 * 3 * 3 = 27 ?

Answer (score 0):

biSizeImage: total size of image in bytes including pixels and padding.

You have biWidth = 3 pixels, 
biBitCount = 24 bitperpixel (8bits = 1byte)

So your image width: 
3pix * (24 / 8 ) bytesperpixel = 9 bytes
9 bytes is not a multiple of 4, and all bmp files have to have row width as a multiple of 4.

So the closest number 4x is 12 bytes.
That means in each row, you will add 3 bytes of zeros 0x00 0x00 0x00.

Now the total size will be:
3pix * (3bytes per pixel) + padding 3 bytes = 12 bytes per row
12 bytes per row * 3 rows = 36 bytes
Hope this helps.
z

Comment: I got it . Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The question is regarding this:
http://cdn.cs50.net/2015/x/psets/4/hacker4/hacker4.html

But the original poster didn't realize that the information above doesn't deal with the 3x3 bmp referenced later in the post, instead it was the 8x8 bmp which was referenced in that information. In which case:

```
8(width)*8(height)*3(bytes/pixel) = 192
```

then add 54 bytes for header files = 246.

This answer is relevant to **bfSize** which is the size of the entire bitmap which the OP thought the information above was referencing.

Instead, the 40 bytes referenced by the OP is actually **biSize** which belongs to the BITMAPINFOHEADER. This variable references the number of bytes required by this header *structure itself.*